# Implementing behaviour of Boost::Asio for a class

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm writing an OpenVPN3 client in where, instead of opening a tun device on the operating system and thus being able to write and read from a file descriptor, I want to interface with OpenVPN3 directly. Thankfully, the OpenVPN3 library makes it possible for me to pass a template parameter different from the one that deals with file descriptors. So in the place of `asio::posix::basic_stream_descriptor` I pass my custom class that simulates/implements the same functions used by `asio::posix::basic_stream_descriptor`. So I need to reimplement the asynchronous behaviour of Boost Asio library in my class.

I'm subclassing a part of OpenVPN3 code that uses `posix::basic_stream_descriptor` in a template, like this:

```
template <typename ReadHandler>
class Tun : public TunIO<ReadHandler, PacketFrom, posix::basic_stream_descriptor>
```

This class mainly uses these two methods from [posix::basic_stream_descriptor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__basic_stream_descriptor.html): [write_some](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor/write_some.html) and [async_read_some](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html).

I'm designing a class called `AsioStyleDequeDescriptor` that implements these methods. Here's my class with the templated parameters substituted by what OpenVPN3 uses:

```
class AsioStyleDequeDescriptor {

    //called by OpenVPN3 to queue asynchronous reads with data from my app
    void async_read_some(
        const boost::asio::mutable_buffer &buffers,
        std::function(void(const boost::asio::error_code, const size_t)) handler);

    //called by OpenVPN3 to write data to be read by my app 
    std::size_t write_some(const boost::asio::const_buffer &buffers);

    //A way for my app to queue some data for OpenVPN3 async_read_some to read
    void queue_read_some(uint8_t* buffer, size_t size);

    //A way for my app to queue callbacks to be called when OpenVPN3 makes data available
    void queue_write_some(std::function<something...> callback);

};
```

The two first functions are meant to substitute `posix::basic_stream_descriptor` so OpenVPN3 can use and the other two are meant to be used by my app. Here are the explanations for the Asio functions:

Now I need a way to efficiently queue all the 4 calls because Asio is meant to return immediately. So I at least need to queue them to a FIFO. I thought of using `std::deque`. So there should be at least 2 `deque`s: one to queue `async_read_some` calls and other for `write_some` calls. I didn't decide yet if I want my app to call AsioStyleDequeDescriptor asynchonously, but let's assume it does. Then I need other 2 `deque`s for the `queue_async_read_some` and `queue_write_some` calls.

Ok, now I need one or more threads to match `async_read_some` with `queue_async_read_some` and `write_some` with `queue_write_some`. I thougth of putting `std::contidion_variable`s in  a way that when data is put into `queue_async_read_some`, `async_read_some` is activated, there goes one thread. And the other thread monitors when data is put into `write_some` that activates `queue_write_some`.

Is this idea good? Am in I the rigth track or can you think of a better approach? Or is there already something that does all that I want?

Comment: You start by implementation details, you should first explain "why", what is your goal at the end, the context.

Comment: @JeanDavy I edited the question, it should be clearer now

Comment: I think you mean "implement an Asio IO object". There's quite a lot of water under the bridge, but I think https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio used to have an example. Not sure whether it was removed